# Finding a File With Specific Permissions

Tags: shell, unix, pipeline

I need to write a command pipeline that will show all non-hidden files that have read permissions for all users.
I dont know why this wouldn't work:

```
find * -perm a=r -print
```

I get no output and am not sure where I am going wrong. Please Help.

Comment: try the `-readable` flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify it as:

```
find * -perm -a+r
```

Note the dash in front of a.

Comment: Oh it works! Thanks a ton. What does the dash represent? and why did you use the plus sign instead of equals?

Comment: from `man find`: * -perm -mode All of the permission bits mode are set for the file. Symbolic modes are accepted in this form, and this is usually the way in which would want to use them. You must specify 'u', 'g' or 'o' if you use a symbolic mode. See the EXAMPLES section for some illustrative examples. *

Answer (score 2):

you should specify this way

find . -type f -perm -a+x or find . -type f -perm -a=x

note that -

or you can use octal also

find . -type f -perm -655

. specify current directory